# KDE notification not clickable in tray

Tags: kubuntu, kde, notification, system-tray

Under KDE 5.17 (on Kubuntu 19.10) the notifications on the desktop are interactive as expected. I can click them to reach the destination (e.g. weblink or a new email).
After the notifications are removed from the desktop, they are shown in the tray. But in there, I can not click them. How can I get those notifications in the tray to be clickable as the desktop version?